# NotImplementedError: No operator found for memory_efficient_attention_forward

Tags: stable-diffusion

Got the following error when running stable diffsion notebook in google colab.

```
NotImplementedError: No operator found for `memory_efficient_attention_forward` with inputs:
 query       : shape=(1, 4096, 1, 512) (torch.float16)
 key         : shape=(1, 4096, 1, 512) (torch.float16)
 value       : shape=(1, 4096, 1, 512) (torch.float16
```

updated xformers but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`!pip install --pre -U xformers` [reference](https://github.com/TheLastBen/fast-stable-diffusion/issues/2690)
this resolved my issue.